# wp_remote_post to admin-ajax.php isn't sending body value

Tags: ajax, api, wp-remote-post

I'm trying to get my code to get the TMDB API data but since the API response contains multiple pages, I'm trying to recursive call my function and increment the page number each time. I'm logging to a file and see that with each recursive call, the body in my request to admin-ajax.php is not being passed and hence the function is being called again for page 1. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
DEFINE( "BASE_URL", "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/" );
DEFINE( "TRENDING_URL", BASE_URL . "trending/movie/day?page=");
DEFINE ("BEARER_TOKEN", 'MY_BEARER_TOKEN'); // Using my real Bearer token here

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_trending_movies', 'get_trending_movies');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_trending_movies', 'get_trending_movies');

function get_trending_movies() {

    $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/report.text'; // Log each recurivse requste to file to check if page number is incrementing

    $current_page = ( ! empty($_POST['current_page']) ) ? $_POST['current_page'] : 1; //Get current page from $_POST variable. If doesn't exist, set to 1

    // SET MAX PAGINATION    
    if( $current_page == 10 ){
        die();
    };
    $trending_movies = [];

    $args = array(
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(
            "Authorization" => BEARER_TOKEN,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ),
        'sslverify' => false,
    );


    $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get(TRENDING_URL . $current_page , $args));

    $file_data = "Current page is: " . $current_page . "\n" . "Current \$_POST['current_page'] = " . $_POST['current_page'] . "\n\n";

    file_put_contents($file, $file_data, FILE_APPEND);

    $results = json_decode( $results ); // JSON decodes the response, which is in JSON format to a PHP array

    
 
    if( ! is_array( $results ) || empty( $results ) ){ // If response is not an array OR response is empty array, then return as we're done.
        return false;
    };


    $current_page = $current_page + 1; // incrementing for getting next page
    
    //Calling function recursively

    $recursive_args = array(
        'blocking' => false,
        'sslverify' => false,
        'body' => [
            'current_page'  => $current_page            
        ]
    );

    $recursive_request = wp_remote_post( admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_trending_movies'), json_encode($recursive_args) );


    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r($results);
    // echo '</pre';


    

};

get_trending_movies();
```

Sorry, I'm learning PHP and WordPress development at the same time so am fumbling and bungling my way around. Also, I am using my real BEARER_TOKEN in the actual code. In fact, when I remove the recursive request to admin-ajax.php

```
    $recursive_request = wp_remote_post( admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_trending_movies'), json_encode($recursive_args) );
```

And echo the response, I am getting the Trending movies in the response. And in looking at my report.txt log, all I see is:

```
Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] = 

Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] = 

Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] = 

Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] = 

Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] = 

Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] = 

Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] = 

Current page is: 1
Current $_POST['current_page'] =
```

So I guess the 'current_page' in the body is not being passed on to admin-ajax.php.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd avoid recursive HTTP requests, HTTP requests are one of the slowest things you can do in WP, nevermind the strong possibility of infinite loops. Also is there a reason you chose to implement the legacy Admin AJAX APi instead of a modern REST API route/endpoint?

Comment: Also would it make more sense to create a separate function to fetch the results, then call it in a loop instead of creating an entire HTTP request? You already have everything you need there, why create a new admin AJAX request to fetch the data when you can just do it there right away?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell To be honest, I only did it this way as this was based on a video I saw on YT. Based on your recommendation, I'm trying to redo this via a function that fetches the data but then calls itself. Could you please tell me a little more about doing it without an AJAX request. Thanks once again.

Comment: You would still use an AJAX request, it would just be to a REST API URL that you chose, rather than `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. AJAX is just javascript making requests to a web server to fetch/send data, it's not a WordPress specific thing it's an Internet thing. The `admin-ajax.php` API tuff though, that's WordPress specific, and quite old at that, so you still get a lot of tutorials about it and people unaware of the newer REST API. Look up the `register_rest_route` function

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell I'll have a look at that approach and go through the ```register_rest_route```